# Multiple Correlation Coefficient for Time Series?

Tags: time-series, correlation

I am using Pearson's correlation coefficient to calculate the correlation between two time series. Now I would like to calculate the correlation between a set of time series A, B, C and the time series D. It should be a many-to-one correlation (A, B, C-->D).

Is there a common approach how to do this?

Is it valid to combine A, B and C by summing or convolution and then calculate the correlation between the aggregated time series (ABC) and D?

Comment: If you considered cross-sectional i.i.d. observations (rather than time series), would you regress D on A, B and C ($D=\beta_0+\beta_1 A+\beta_2 B+\beta_3 C+\varepsilon$), obtain fitted values $\hat{D}$ and take $corr(D,\hat{D})$? Is that what you are looking for, but in a time series context?

Comment: yes exactly, for cross-sectional obersvations it could be done with regression.

But what do you think about the approach merging the time series into one series and apply the cross correlation calculation?

Comment: What subject-matter question are you trying to answer so that you want to use something like multiple correlation?

Comment: the context is finding out the cause (A, B, C) of a system failure (D), so when A, B causes the failure often and C very infrequently, it wouldn't correlate with D. The idea was to combine A, B, C to explain each system failure in my time series D and use that information for variable selection.

Comment: A simple model reflecting your situation might be ARIMA with D as the dependent variable and A, B, C as external regressors. Function `auto.arima` in "forecast" package in "R" would do. You should be able to obtain $corr(D,\hat{D})$ afterwards.